# URL of gallery-hosted Safari extension plist update manifest

Tags: safari-extension

I assume that the Safari extension Gallery provides a plist update manifest just like you have to provide one for a self-hosted extension.
But what is its URL?

Comment: Why do you need the url for? The updates for extensions hosted in Gallery are done automatically, without any changes to your extension plist file.

Comment: @PotecaruTudor I'd like to programmatically get the version number of the currently released extension.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve it from outside the extension? safari.extension.displayVersion will do that in your extension code, but I guess that's not what you're after.

Comment: @PotecaruTudor Yes, it's for a management tool outside the browser extension.